# Increase the size of the toast in google sheets/ google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a code written to validate some blank cells and display a toast with the label names which are not filled, Since the label names are lengthy and too many, the toast opo is not able to show the names of all labels as below -

[image]

My script is as below-

```
function validation() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rg1= sheet.getRange('B9');
  var rg2 = sheet.getRange('D9')
  var rg3 = sheet.getRange('F9')
  var rg4 = sheet.getRange('H9')
  var rg5 = sheet.getRange('B13')
  var rg6 = sheet.getRange('D13')
  var rg7 = sheet.getRange('B26')
  var rg8 = sheet.getRange('D26')
  var rg9 = sheet.getRange('B30')

  var ranges = [rg1, rg2, rg3,rg4,rg5,rg6,rg7,rg8,rg9];
  var unfilled = [];

  for(var range of ranges) {
    if(range.isBlank()) {
      unfilled.push(range.offset(-1,0).getValue())
      range.setBackground('red');
      } else {range.setBackground(null)};
  }

  if(unfilled.length == 0) SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("All filled", "Thank you",10);
  else {
    unfilled = unfilled.join(", ");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Please fill - " + unfilled, "⚠️ Unfilled data",10);
  }
}
```

Can I increase the size of the toast? or use use two toasts to break the info and display, or any other way I can show the names of the fields.

Please help!

Comment: I don’t think so

Comment: You can use the standard alert window: `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Your message is here')`

Comment: You can use a modeless window to but prrobably not as simply as a toast

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the comments it would be important to leave an answer for the future.

The documentation on how the API works or features in general using Sheet it is not possible to add size or adjust the way the toast is presented or variables that you can add, for example:

- toast(msg, title, timeoutSeconds)

The second suggestion also works great as it shows a bigger alert and you can add buttons to it, example:

[image]

This could be achieved by utilizing a sample code like:

```js
function alertMessageOKButton() {
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Alert message", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(result);
}
```

You can also share your feedback or request the feature for the future here:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support

References:

- [Alert Messages in Google Sheets](https://spreadsheet.dev/pop-up-alert-messages-in-google-sheets)
- [Toast Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg,-title,-timeoutseconds)